# Which situations cause "Use of instruction is not an instruction" in LLVM IR?

Tags: llvm

I keep getting this error many times. Then, when I shift things around it works. My code is too complex to post here. I can't simplify and reproduce the problem.

The source code in LLVM that raises an exception is here: http://llvm.org/doxygen/Verifier_8cpp_source.html:

```
   // Check that all uses of the instruction, if they are instructions
   // themselves, actually have parent basic blocks.  If the use is not an
   // instruction, it is an error!
   for (Use &U : I.uses()) {
     if (Instruction *Used = dyn_cast<Instruction>(U.getUser()))
       Assert(Used->getParent() != nullptr,
              "Instruction referencing"
              " instruction not embedded in a basic block!",
              &I, Used);
     else {
       CheckFailed("Use of instruction is not an instruction!", U);
       return;
     }
   }
```

But I still don't understand what it means

So, I wonder if anyone has **a small example** that cause the "Use of instruction is not an instruction" error and also explain why it happens.

Thank you!

Comment: Why exactly can't you make a smaller example from your current code? Your code is probably saved in a repository, which means you can delete some uninteresting part, try to compile it and if it still shows the error, even commit it to a local branch. Repeat until you have a small example.

Comment: I did that in multiple combinations. The problem disappeared and etc. It's definitely because I'm new to LLVM. So, I want take a different route of understanding this error by understanding a small example that causes it instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably generating bogus IR somewhere in your code. The assertion you mention might be triggered by, for example, constructing a constant expression that uses result of other instruction as operand:

```
%0 = <some instruction producing result>
store i8* getelementptr inbounds ([123 x i8], [123 x i8]* @some_string, i32 %0, i32 0), ...
```

Here, the `getelementptr inbounds ...` part is a [constant expression](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#constant-expressions), which can't contain anything except other constants. Hence, we can't use `%0` as indices here.

Instead, we need to use `getelementptr` **instruction**:

```
%0 = <some instruction producing result>
%1 = i8* getelementptr inbounds ([123 x i8], [123 x i8]* @some_string, i32 %0, i32 0)
store i8* %1, ...
```

As for your case, you can just call `I.dump()` from your code or inside debugger to figure out what instruction causes failed assertion exactly.

Comment: Let me get this right. We merely need to store the result in an intermediate variable to make it a non-constant, right? Coming from a normal programming language, this is a huge gotcha. I didn't even realise the above 2 code were not equivalent. Could you point to more explanation around this concept? What is this concept called? I'd like to read more.

Comment: More question: I notice that it only fails when verifying the function. What happens if we just go ahead and run the code anyway? How would it be wrong? Thank you!

Comment: For my specific problem, I'm stuck with this: `Use of instruction is not an instruction!
  %size_with_terminator = add i32 %cstring_size, 1`. I'm not sure how to solve it. The line is already on its own.

Comment: I've figured it out. I later used `%size_with_terminator` in another constant expression. The error was misleading; It was the use of `%size_with_terminator`, not the declaration of `%size_with_terminator`. Do you have any trick to figure this out quickly? It failed when verifying a function, so I couldn't even run it. Thank you for the pointer. It really helps me understand LLVM better.

Comment: I'm using debugger for this. All of `Instruction`, `BasicBlock`, `Function` and `Module` classes have `dump()` method that prints corresponding IR. Whenever assertion fails, the debuggers breaks and allows you to inspect IR on which Verifier choked.

Comment: Oh, that's true. Thank you!